# How to perform action for a menu item only when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have piece of code which is having a sign in page, if we click on sign in button a dialog will pop up. Suppose I want to navigate to a particular page only when particular item in the drop down is selected and save button of the dialog is clicked. Is there a way to check if particular item in the menu is selected and action associated with the menu item should be performed only when button is clicked. Thanks in advance.

```js
<script src="./Signin Template for Bootstrap_files/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });

        //code for dialog
        $("#dialog-form").dialog
        ({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            zIndex: 1,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    if ($("#name").val() == "" || $("#name").val().length < 5) {
                        $("#name").addClass("error");
                        $("#name").val('');
                    }
                    if ($("#password").val() == "" || $("#password").val().length < 5) {
                        $("#password").addClass("error");
                        $("#password").val('');
                    }
                    if ($("#email").val() == "" || $("#email").val().length < 5) {
                        $("#email").addClass("error");
                        $("#email").val('');
                    }

                    $('.dropdown-menu>li:nth-child(1)').click(function () {

                        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                    });

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#name").val('');
                    $("#password").val('');
                    $("#email").val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0040)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/ -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./Signin Template for Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="./Signin Template for Bootstrap_files/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./Signin Template for Bootstrap_files/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="./Signin Template for Bootstrap_files/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error {
            border-color: #F00
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" id="#sign-in">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" id="btn1">Sign in</button>
    </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Form"></div>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <form id="register" name="register" action=" " method=" ">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="true" email="true"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Male</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Female</label>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Dropdown
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#">ECE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AEEE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSE</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">First year</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need a cleaner explanation ,you want to restrict access to non-users ?

Comment: @Prasad, you want to navigate the page with respect to the values selected in the "dropdown" right?

Comment: also the action should take place only when save button is clicked

Comment: y cant you use $("#buttonname").click(function(){ .... });

Comment: can you make jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       //remove the selected class from the element 
       $('.abc a').removeClass('selected')
       $('.abc a').click( function(){
          //add the class to the selected element  
          $(this).addClass('selected')
       })

       $('#btn1').click(function(){
            var selectedLocation = $('.abc a.selected').attr('href')
            window.location = selectedLocation
       })
   });
```

You don't have any location in your dropdown yet, but I suppose you well know that!

Comment: Thanks Franco. Is there a way that this action should be performed only when "Save" button of the dialog box is clicked. If I insert this code the page is redirecting after changing menu item but I need the action only after clicking save button of the dialog box.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is important to you that the user MUST make a selection before pushing that button? If yes, tI have to make some other changes to the code

Comment: Thanks for your response Franco, it is not that important.

Comment: As now the code is, If you click on the button the code will check for the location, and if this is not selected you will probably get 'undefined', so it will be important to check for this in the code. I hope you know how to do this. If not let me know and I will change the code for you. If this answer works for you then please check it as accepted. This will be useful for other users. THanks